# How can I add my own contact form in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a site in wordpress 3, i wanted to add a newsletter signup form, im confused where I can add the php code for the form to work,
Please help

Comment: should be on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you would need a plugin to allow php code in a custom_sidebar as suggested by Pigi. You could just add it to the sidebar.php file, but it would appear in all areas of your site with the sidebar enabled. You might want to save the code for your form in a separate file for example:

If this were the form:

```
<ol class="yourForm">
   <li><label for="contactName">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="contactName" id="contactName" value="<?php 
      if(isset($_POST['contactName'])) echo $_POST['contactName'];?>" class="requiredField" />
  <?php if($nameError != '') { ?><span class="error"><?=$nameError;?></span><?php 
  } ?></li>
   <li><label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="
    <?php if(isset($_POST['email']))  echo $_POST['email'];?>"class="requiredField email" />
    <?php if($emailError != '') { ?>
     <span class="error"><?=$emailError;?></span><?php 
  } ?></li>
   <li class="textarea"><label for="commentsText">Comments</label>
    <textarea name="comments" id="commentsText" rows="20" cols="30" class="requiredField">
    <?php if(isset($_POST['comments'])) { 
     if(function_exists('stripslashes')) { 
      echo stripslashes($_POST['comments']); 
     } else { 
      echo $_POST['comments']; 
     }
     } 
  ?></textarea>
    <?php if($commentError != '') { ?>
     <span class="error"><?=$commentError;?></span><?php 
  } ?></li>
   <li class="inline"><input type="checkbox" name="sendCopy" id="sendCopy" value="true"
    <?php if(isset($_POST['sendCopy']) && $_POST['sendCopy'] == true) 
     echo ' checked="checked"'; ?> />
    <label for="sendCopy">Send a copy of this email to yourself</label></li>
   <li class="screenReader">
    <label for="checking" class="screenReader">If you want to submit this form, do not enter anything in this field</label>
    <input type="text" name="checking" id="checking" class="screenReader" value="
    <?php if(isset($_POST['checking']))  echo $_POST['checking'];?>"/></li>
   <li class="buttons">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
    <button type="submit">Email me »</button></li>
</ol>
```

You would save it as form.php and upload it to your themes root directory.

You could then **add it to all sidebars** by placing this piece of code in the sidebar.php file:

```
<div id="myForm"><?php get_template_part('form'); ?></div>
```

Or **just on certain pages** using a conditional statement like this:

```
<?php if (is_page_template('index.php')) {
  get_template_part('form');
  } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful help..., I have one doubt that is how can I add functional code for sending email, and how can I call that files in this form

Answer (score 0):

you can add it in the sidebar, before the "dynamic_sidebar" function.

for example:

```
 HERE YOUR FORM CODE    
<?php /* Widgetized sidebar */
        if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar() ) : ?><?php endif; ?>
```

Check the php tags, be sure that when embedding form code php is closed!